# Returning asynchronous response in sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sails.js

My app needs to return a JSON response after some DB queries.

Pseudocode (using `async`):

```
async.forEachOf(sails.config.site.regions, function (regionData, slug) {
        obj['regions'][slug] = {
            'slug': slug,
            'name': regionData.name,
        };
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({
                'error': true,
                'message': 'Error when retrieving data from the DB'
            });
        }
        else {
            res.json(obj);
            return;
        }
    });
```

Sails hangs since no response seems to be returned from the service.

I tried converting this to a Promise (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886627/javascript-sails-js-controller-waiting-for-service-to-call-async-function)) but it doesn't work either.

How can I do this?

Comment: does the service work if you access from a tool like postman? - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: Maybe it's just your pseudocode, but [you're using `async.forEachOf` incorrectly](https://github.com/caolan/async#forEachOf).  The second argument (the function to be called for each item in the array) needs a callback that you call within the function to continue the loop.  You should just post your real code; pseudocode isn't much help here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
async.forEachOf(sails.config.site.regions, function (regionData, slug) {
        obj['regions'][slug] = {
            'slug': slug,
            'name': regionData.name,
        };
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.json({
                'error': true,
                'message': 'Error when retrieving data from the DB'
            });
        }
        else {
            return res.json(obj);

        }
    });
```